# How do I remove Swing JSplitPane intermediate styles?

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

How do I remove Swing `JSplitPane` intermediate styles?

### BasicSplitPaneDivider

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/97rrg.png]

Comment: Playing with the UI is rarely worth the effort since you would need to do it for all platforms you want you code to run on. But you can look at the `BasicSplitPaneDivider` which is used in the `BasicSplitPaneUI`. Your platform will likely extend each of those classes to give the custom LAF for the platform. So you would need to create a custom UI and divider.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment the proper solution is to create a custom `BasicSplitPaneDivider`.

As a hack you can access the divider and add your own button to it:

```
    BasicSplitPaneUI ui = (BasicSplitPaneUI)splitPane.getUI();
    BasicSplitPaneDivider divider = ui.getDivider();

    divider.setDividerSize(25);
    JButton up = (JButton)divider.getComponent(0);
    up.setPreferredSize( up.getSize() );
    up.setMaximumSize(up.getPreferredSize());
    up.setAlignmentY(0.5f);

    JButton down = (JButton)divider.getComponent(1);
    down.setPreferredSize( down.getSize() );
    down.setMaximumSize(down.getPreferredSize());
    down.setAlignmentY(0.5f);

    divider.setLayout( new BoxLayout(divider, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    divider.add(up);
    divider.add(down);
    divider.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    System.out.println(divider.getLayout());
    JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
    button.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    divider.add(button);
    divider.revalidate();
    divider.repaint();
```

The above code would need to be executed AFTER the frame has been realized.

In any case the above will demonstrate the type of changes that need to be made to the `BasicSplitPaneDivider` class.