# JTabbedPane Achieve mouse change height

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtabbedpane

Idea has a console window that looks like it's implemented with JTabbedPane

Console window image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9LAx.png]

Can change the size by hovering over it:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTzen.png]

How do implement this UI effect in Swing?

JTabbedPane can have a similar effect, but cannot change the height with the mouse.

Comment: Put it in a `JSplitPane`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson FYI that was the OP's first question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336246/how-do-i-remove-swing-jsplitpane-intermediate-styles

Comment: The component isn’t implemented using a JTabbedPane (it’s open source so you can see yourself how it’s done). As your other questions imply that you are wanting to implement the whole tabbed frame component yourself you may want to look at the following implementation of something very similar: https://github.com/weisJ/darklaf/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/github/weisj/darklaf/components/tabframe/JTabFrame.java

Comment: nice thank u!   :)

Comment: I solved my problem based on FlatLaf and put the code on GitHub.

[https://github.com/Richard-Tang/FlatLafTabFrame](https://github.com/Richard-Tang/FlatLafTabFrame)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem based on FlatLaf and put the code on GitHub.

https://github.com/Richard-Tang/FlatLafTabFrame

[show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIGCB.gif)

```java
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    if (isDragged) {
        Dimension size = getSize();
        size.height += clickDraggedPanelPosition;
        size.height += Math.negateExact(e.getY());
        setPreferredSize(size);
        updateUI();
    }
}
```

The key code is to change the height of the JPanel with setPreferredSize() and UpdateUI() as you drag.